Migradoc wraps text between hyperlink and punctuation
I have implemented a PDF report generator in C# using Migradoc. It generates a series of tables populated with data extracted from an Excel document. Each row in these tables is a definition of an object with a unique identifier. Some objects have a description that contain references to other objects by their identifier, e.g. "Yada yada (see GEN1001)."
The extracted data is just pure text. In the report, the generator adds a bookmark for every object (table row), and replaces the textual references with a hyperlink to the referenced object. That is, the example "Yada yada (see GEN1001).", which is just text in the Excel document, looks the same in the PDF, except that "GEN1001" is a hyperlink.
This works just fine, but it looks... less fine.
The problem is text wrapping. Before I added the hyperlinks, the example might be wrapped like this in a cell:
Yada yada (see
GEN1001).
...which is just as expected. But after I made (in this case) GEN1001 a hyperlink, I get this instead:
Yada yada (see GEN1001
).
...which is just wrong. You do not break a line between a word and punctuation.
This is the local function that is invoked to add a paragraph to a cell. It replaces any identifiers with hyperlinks.
Paragraph AddPara(string paragraphText)
{
    var para = cell.AddParagraph();
    var rest = paragraphText;

    while (rest.Length > 0)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(rest,
            @"^(?<FRONT>.*?)\b(?<CODE>(?:GEN|FI|FM|MDR|CT)\d{4})\b(?<BACK>.*)$");

        if (match.Success)
        {
            para.AddText(match.Groups["FRONT"].Value);
            rest = match.Groups["BACK"].Value;
            var code = match.Groups["CODE"].Value;
            var bookmark = code.StartsWith("GEN")
                ? $"{domainKey}_{code}"
                : code;

            var hyperLink = para.AddHyperlink(bookmark);
            hyperLink.AddText(code);

            continue;
        }

        para.AddText(rest);

        break;
    }

    return para;
}

I thought of placing the hyperlink inside a Text object, but that does not seem possible. I also tried to set different properties on the hyperlink object in code above and on the Hyperlink style, but found nothing that helped.
And I tried googling of course. Lots of hits on wrapping and hyperlinks, but I did not find anything related to this - perhaps I am just using incorrect terminology.
Can anyone help me with this?
